# retrieving json data by a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

```
  const username = 'merMan';

  fetch("./datz.json")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);

    })
```

my data `response` looks like below, still having a difficult time simply getting a user specific data. My `response` data outputs like below. I have tried using `find`, but always returns find is not a function, `response[username]` does not work either.

```
[{"mermAn":{"baseMapId":"459cc334740944d38580455a0a777a24","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935"},
{"catWoman":{"baseMapId":"459cc334740944d38580455a0a777a24","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935"},
{"Riddler":{"baseMapId":"459cc334740944d38580455a0a777a24","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935"}}]
```

Comment: The response is JSON. Then why do you call `.text()` instead of `.json()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the response after `response.text()`, like:

```js
fetch("./datz.json")
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {
        try {
          const parsedArray = JSON.parse(response);

          console.log(parsedArray);
        } catch (error) {
          // response could not be parsed
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) instead of [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)

```js
const username = 'merMan';

fetch("./datz.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((users) => {
      console.log(users.find(x => typeof x[username] !== "undefined"));
  })
```